How to reset layout in sveltekit?
How can I reset layout inheritance in Svelte?
Parent
I have a parent layout at src/routes/+layout.svelte:
<script>
  import Header from "$lib/components/Header.svelte";
</script>
<Header/>
<slot/>

Home page result


Child
In a child route, src/routes/(admin)/+layout@.svelte, I want to reset the layout inheritance. This +layout@.svelte supposed to work, but for some reason it doesn't. The header component from the parent layout still persists in dashboard page. Currently, my +layout@.svelte looks like this:
<slot/>

Dashboad page result

However, the header from src/routes/+layout.svelte still appears. How can I properly reset the layout inheritance so that the child layout does not include the parent header?
Folder structure
routes/
  ├── (admin)/
  │   └── dashboard/
  │   |       ├── +page.svelte
  │   └── +layout@.svelte
  ├── styles.css
  ├── +layout.svelte
  ├── +page.svelte
  ├── +page.ts
  └── app.html


The root layout always applies.
If you want to be able to not have any layout content, make the root layout just a <slot />, create a group for everything and only put content in the group's layout.

When you do this, did you put  header and footer components inside of root's +page.svelte, instead?

No, you put everything in the new group's layout.
